# How to create filterable portfolio in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a Portfolio custom page in WordPress, so far I've been able to get the categories from the custom taxonomy.

Now what I want is when clicking on an option, it should fetch the post with the custom category.

This is what I have so far:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-default" data-toggle="portfilter" data-target="all">All</button>
     <?php 
                        $terms = get_terms("portfolio_categories"); // Consigue todas las categorias del custom taxonomy.
                        $termsString .=  $term->slug;
                        $count = count($terms); //Cuantos categorias son?
                        if ( $count > 0 ){  //Si es que hay mas de uno
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //Para cada termino:
                                echo "<button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' data-toggle='portfilter' data-target='".$term->slug."'>".$term->name."</button>\n";
                            }
                        } 
                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

<div class="row">
  <?php
          $portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolios','order' => 'DESC',));
        ?>     
<?php if($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : while($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post(); $terms_portfolio = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories'); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4" data-tag="<?php echo $terms_portfolio[0]->slug; ?>">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-page'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="caption">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php  else : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center"><p>Ningun portfolio encontrado</p></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The categories are working fine, but I'm still unable to get the slug for the `data-tag` that is inside the `<div class="col-md-4" data-tag="this is what I need">`

Can somebody help me with this, please?

Here is the current status:

[image]

Comment: `get_terms` returns an array, so even if you actually did something with the return value (no `echo` there), you would end up with something like `data-tag="Array"` ... so the actual question becomes, what specific value do you _need_ there in the first place?

Comment: If you say you need the slug there, then why is it not just `data-tag="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"` (plus of course an appropriate escaping function, depending on what that value might contain.)

Comment: I already tried it sir, and yet I found myself unable to do it.(That was the first try I did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
$terms_portfolio = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories');

<div class="col-md-4" data-tag="<?php echo $terms_portfolio[0]->slug); ?>">
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, then I replaced the `$terms[0]` by `$term` and it actually "kinda" worked but only with the last category.

Comment: `<div class="col-md-4" data-tag="portfolio-category-5"></div>`

Comment: could you please check by adding this what the output of  $terms,
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories');

print_r($terms);

Comment: this should work i dont know what going wrong  debug the output by adding this      print_r(get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_categories'));

Comment: i have updated the answer did you updated yours accordingly

Comment: the custom texonomy 'portfolio_categories' which you have created , is it attached with custom post type 'portfolios' ?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm pretty sure about it.

Comment: Is now fixed, you can check the code, I just "switched" places. I was calling the loop way too early.